# Curious sql import syntax error

Tags: mysql, import, wamp

I'm re-importing a MySQL DB from my laptop to PC. I exported my WAMP MySQL `.sql` file, and am now trying to import it on my PC. This has always worked in the past, and I've since only changed a couple tables around... but now I'm getting the following error:

```
  #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
  to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
  'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `join_quests_npcs` (
  `jqn_id` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_' at line 16
```

Info:

```
Desktop WAMP MySQL ver: `5.5.16`, 
Laptop WAMP MySQL ver: `5.6.12`   
File to import: char set of file: `utf 8`
Format: `sql` 
Format-specific options: SQL compatibility mode: `none`
```

But I don't think this little difference in WAMP version would cause a syntax error like this.

I also don't see anything wrong with what it's complaining about... Here's the block it's complaining about from the exported `.sql` file I'm trying to now import:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `join_quests_npcs` (
  `jqn_id` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `quest_id` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `npc_id` int(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`jqn_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=15 ;
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

---

EDIT:

**Also curious:**

The first table in the `.sql` file is created with no issue:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.0.4
-- http://www.phpmyadmin.net
--
-- Host: localhost
-- Generation Time: Oct 27, 2014 at 09:15 PM
-- Server version: 5.6.12-log
-- PHP Version: 5.4.12

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

--
-- Database: `my_test_db_2014`
--
    CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `my_test_db_2014` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
    USE `my_test_db_2014`;

    -- --------------------------------------------------------

    --
    -- Table structure for table `gather_items`
    --
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gather_items` (
  `item_id` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `item_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `item_chinese` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `item_x` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `item_y` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `item_image` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `item_total` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `item_cost` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`item_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `gather_item_id` (`item_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `gather_items`
--

INSERT INTO `gather_items` (`item_id`, `item_name`, `item_chinese`, `item_x`, `item_y`, `item_image`, `item_total`, `item_cost`) VALUES

(1, 'rice', 'fàn', 60, 255, 'data/img/sprite/rice.png', 1, 10),
(2, 'water', 'shui', 30, 400, 'data/img/sprite/poly.png', 3, 40),
(3, 'meat', 'rou', 500, 100, 'data/img/sprite/meat.png', 1, 100);

-- --------------------------------------------------------
```

Errors out on creation of this table:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `join_quests_npcs`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `join_quests_npcs` (
  `jqn_id` int(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `quest_id` int(6) NOT NULL,
  `npc_id` int(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`jqn_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=15 ;
```

---

EDIT 2:

So I removed `join_quest_npcs` table creation to see if it would still complain, and now it's erroring out again on the next block below... So I think it's somehow related to the `gather_items` first table creation.

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `levels` (
  `level_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `levelnam' at line 17
```

SQL block:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `levels`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `levels` (
  `level_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `levelname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `associatedQuestIDs` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`level_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `levels`
--

INSERT INTO `levels` (`level_id`, `levelname`, `associatedQuestIDs`) VALUES
(1, 'mymap', '101 102 103'),
(2, 'mymap2', '201 202');
```

Comment: A quick check of the release notes doesn't reveal anything.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Good thought. Then I'm completely stumped. This is typically a routine export/import for me.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Do you think the encoding could have anything to do with it? I have special chars (Chinese characters) in some of my fields, so I'm using `utf8`.

Comment: Hmmmm - shouldn't. What is right *before* that creation chunk? It is possible that MySQL is complaining about that.

Comment: @JayBlanchard Added it above

Comment: I just ran all of this and had no issue with it. No errors were thrown and the tables were created properly. There is something else afoot here.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I found the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it. The issue is from the first table creation: `gather_items`, and not from where MySQL is complaining...

Specifically, it's from the insertion of this line, which contains a utf-8 special character, `fàn`. The accent mark was breaking the insertion.

`(1, 'rice', 'fàn', 60, 255, 'data/img/sprite/rice.png', 1, 10),`

When I insert as plain text, `fan`, all rows were inserted properly.

And I think the issue is because even though I'm creating the table with default charset=UTF8

```
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And even though I'm specifying my char set on import to utf8:

[image]

The DB import script specified char set `latin1`:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `my_test_db_2014` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
```

So, I need to change my script's `DEFAULT CHARACTER SET` to utf8

You also need to change to the proper collation from `latin1_swedish_ci` to `utf8_general_ci` as specified here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-charsets.html